# Is there a way of creating .fits mosaics with astropy?

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I want to create a mosaic using the different HDUs inside a unique .fits file, just as you can when using SAOimage DS9 and selecting "File > Open as > Mosaic WCS". When I searched on how to do this using astropy i encountered reproject and tried to follow the tutorial at https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mosaicking.html. However, I can't seem to make it work for me.

I have an HDUList object when I open the file, so i tried following the "reproject_and_coadd" documentation (https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/reproject.mosaicking.reproject_and_coadd.html#reproject.mosaicking.reproject_and_coadd) and use some other parameters that were not used in the tutorial. This is the code I've been trying to use:

```py
f = fits.open(input_file, memmap=True)
print(f)
array, footprint = reproject_and_coadd(input_data=f, output_projection=f[5].header, hdu_in=f[0].header, reproject_function=reproject_interp)
f.close()
```

The output for f is the following list (when i do type(f) I get it saying that it's an HDUList):

```
[<astropy.io.fits.hdu.image.PrimaryHDU object at 0x7fdcc468aa50>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc462aa10>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc4632690>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc462a110>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc4638310>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc463bf50>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc4642b90>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc4649810>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc464e4d0>, <astropy.io.fits.hdu.compressed.CompImageHDU object at 0x7fdcc4655150>]
```

And the error I'm currently getting is:

```
WARNING: FITSFixedWarning: The WCS transformation has more axes (2) than the image it is associated with (0) [astropy.wcs.wcs]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oi/border.py", line 74, in make_pieces
    array, footprint = reproject_and_coadd(input_data=f[1:9], output_projection=f[0].header, hdu_in=f[0].header, reproject_function=reproject_interp)
  File "/home/oi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reproject/mosaicking/coadd.py", line 91, in reproject_and_coadd
    shape_out=shape_out)
  File "/home/oi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reproject/utils.py", line 98, in parse_output_projection
    raise ValueError("The shape of the output image should not be an "
ValueError: The shape of the output image should not be an empty tuple
```

I'd be really happy if anyone is able to help me :)

Also, if possible, is there a way of opening just two component images and making a mosaic with them? So instead of opening all the 9 tiles at a time, just get tile11 and tile12. I'm new to messing around with .fits, so this would also be cool to know.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but according to the docs for [`reproject_and_coadd`](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/reproject.mosaicking.reproject_and_coadd.html#reproject.mosaicking.reproject_and_coadd), if `input_file` is a FITS file, the `hdu_in` argument is supposed to be the index or EXTNAME of the HDU to use, not a header.

Answer (score 1):

Just remembered I had made this question a while ago! I found out what was the problem I was having.

Considering the .fits file has 9 tiles it's possible to create a full mosaic using:

```py
f = fits.open(filename, memmap=True)
orig_header = f[0].header

# full mosaic: f[1:10]; mosaic from tile11 and tile12: f[1:3]
wcs_out, shape_out = find_optimal_celestial_wcs(f[1:10]) # has only CompImageHDU files

array, footprint = reproject_and_coadd(f[1:10], wcs_out, shape_out=shape_out, reproject_function=reproject_interp)
```

Where `array` is the mosaic, that can then be plotted using matplotlib, for example. The `reproject_and_coadd` function is very memory intensive, though.